# Order to sell bond / stock at one of two prices crossed, rather than one price

Tags: bonds, selling

I am totally new to investing not always have time to monitor the current bond price.  I would like to know if it is possible when selling a bond or stock to set a price range, for e.g. To sell if either the instrument value reaches a high of 1.08 or a stop order if it reaches 1.05.

Is this something which one can do when trading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *Contingent Order* and is set up so if one order is filled (in this case) the other order is cancelled. 
It's a common desire that one would wish to have a stop-loss in place but also a targeted sell price for their in-the-money sell point.

Your broker will tell you all you need to know about how to enter this, if you explain you'd like to place a contingent order. (As Victor noted below, your specific order would be a "*One Cancels Other*" or "OCO")

Great first question, welcome to Money,SE.

Comment: +1, yes and most brokers would call this type of contingent order a "One Cancels Other" or "OCO" contingent order.

Comment: Many thanks all of you! :) I'll check with my broker about this.